# Spring MVC - HTTP Status 400 - The request sent by the client is syntactically incorrect

Tags: spring-mvc

I am getting HTTP 400 error when I submit data through my form. Below is the code. I am not understanding where I have gone wrong.

Course.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name="COURSES")
public class Course {

@Id
@Column(name="id", length=5, unique=true, nullable=false, updatable = false)
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private int id;

@Column(name="COURSE_CODE", length=20, unique=true, nullable=false)
private String courseCode;

@Column(name="COURSE_NAME", length=30, nullable=false)
private String courseName;

@Column(name="COURSE_DESCRIPTION", length=200)
private String courseDescription;

//getters and setters
```

CourseController.java

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/courses/add", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String addCoursePage(WebRequest request, ModelMap model) {
    Course course = new Course();
    model.addAttribute("course", course);
    return "addCourse";
}

@RequestMapping(value= "/courses/save", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String saveCourse(@Valid @ModelAttribute("course") Course r, BindingResult result){

    if (result.hasErrors()) {
        return "redirect:/courses/list";
    }

    this.courseService.addCourse(r);

    return "redirect:/courses/list";        
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/courses/list", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String coursesListPage(ModelMap model) {
    model.addAttribute("coursesList", this.courseService.listAllCourses());
    return "courseList";
}
```

addCourse.jsp

```
<div>
<c:url var="saveAction" value="/courses/save" ></c:url>
<form:form modelAttribute="course" action="${saveAction}" method="POST">
<tr>
<td>
    <form:input type="hidden" path="id" />
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td><label><spring:message text="Course Code"></spring:message></label> 
            <form:input path="courseCode" />            
    </td>
    <form:errors path="courseCode"/>
</tr>

<tr>
    <td><label><spring:message text="Course Name"></spring:message></label>
            <form:input path="courseName" />
    </td>
    <form:errors path="courseName"/>
</tr>

<tr>
    <td><label><spring:message text="Course Description"></spring:message>
        </label>
    </td>
    <td><form:input path="courseDescription" /></td>
    <form:errors path="courseDescription" />
</tr>       
 <tr>
    <td>
            <input type="submit"
                value="<spring:message text="Add course"/>" />
    </td>
</tr>
</form:form>
</div>
```

Comment: Do you still get an error if you remove @Valid from saveCourse method ??

Comment: Pranav, yes I am still getting the same error even after removing @Valid annotation.

Comment: I hope int is not causing the issue, since the value of id will be null while coming from the Page... Try out Int instead of int , if it helps.. It not then I dont have any further clue ...

Comment: id will be auto generated during save. So it should not be a problem as far as I know. Even if it is causing the error, then it should be binding validation error and not 400 right?

Comment: Probably yes.. But another issue I see is with <form:input type="hidden" path="id" /> ... There is no type field in the spring input documentation..

Comment: For hidden field there is <form:hidden/> tag available.. probably you want to try that... You can search for hidden tag in documentation... http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/2.5.x/reference/view.html#view-jsp-formtaglib

Comment: This problem is really puzzling to me. Actually, I have many forms in my application and this 400 status error occurs on few forms and other few forms work properly without any errors. I have even tried changing the tags of hidden fields, but it does not seem to have any effect on the issue. In some forms it works with both kinds of hidden tags and in some fields it does not work for both tags. I am really confused. Why is it working for some forms and not for others?

Comment: hmm.. interesting.. but I have no further clue..... But please do post your findings here once you find the root cause...

Comment: I have understood the root cause of the problem. The problem is that the model attribute "course" is not working properly. The "course" attribute added in the addCoursePage method is not accessible in the saveCourse method. So, @ModelAttribute("course") is giving 400 error. But I am not understanding why the model attribute is not accessible and is there any other way of accessing the model attribute inside saveCourse method without the annotation?

Comment: @PranavManiar As a work around for this problem, I am using RequestParam to fetch the form data and then setting the values to the Course object. I am not understanding why ModelAttribute gives 400 error. Some forms are working properly and some forms are throwing 400 error after submit.